# Jenkins Execute Windows batch command fails for file change

Tags: windows, batch-file, jenkins, cmd

I am trying to change text in a config file using Jenkins Windows batch command but its giving the following error.

```
(Get-Content config_qa.properties )  | {$_ -replace "test123", "test"}   | Set-Content config_qa.properties
```

Ran the above in jenkins windows batch command. below is the error message.

```
'{$_' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure
[workspace] $ cmd /c call C:\windows\TEMP\hudson2235664364282200461.bat
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you didn't miss WHERE operator (after first pipe)?
Like:

```
(Get-Content config_qa.properties ) | where {$_ -replace "test123", "test"} | Set-Content config_qa.properties
```

EDIT:
Also, you need to make sure that Jenkins is trying to run this in PowerShell, not Windows batch (default)